# Image not showing up after posting C++ resource.rc code

Tags: bug, markdown, asking-questions, images

[image]

Here is how the markup code looks like in the post:

[image]

Posting two linebreaks in HTML fixes the broken image.

[image: Fixed]

The final result does not look bad, but there are too many line breaks:

[image: Final result]

Here is my question: *[How to center align Toolbar C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65274732/how-to-center-align-toolbar-c)*

Comment: Not sure, if this relates to your problem, but ditch the `<br/>` tags please. For hard line breaks in paragraphs use two blanks at the end of the line, and a normal line break (just enter).

Comment: 2 blank line breaks did the trick thanks, I guess I could keep doing that, I just got a habit to type `<br>`'s lol

Comment: also want to note that doing 2 line breaks after code, extends the code formatting to whatever you want to type after so `<br>` is a good way to break the code formatting.

Comment: Unrelated to the bug, but consider using the new `\`\`\`code fence\`\`\``, it will be more convenient (also less indentation).